# I am not getting the attribute value of the html element using Jquery

Tags: jquery

In the code I am using Jquery where it is not taking attribute value and not alerting it also I am in the for loop but it is only giving for first values and not for the other values.

my code:
JQuery:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#rid").on('click', function (e) {
        var v = $("#rid").attr('reel');
        alert("hello");
    });
});
```

and HTML:-

```
        <a href="#" id="rid" reel="4">Click me</a>
```

Please tell me what is the error in this and how to remove it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ? There are many potential errors here so let's avoid the guessing game.

Comment: `I am in the for loop but it is only giving for first values and not for the other values` .. where is your for loop

Comment: There is **no** Error!

Comment: looks just fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q7fmQ/1/

Comment: Yep, your code above – by itself – works just fine so I'm assuming that there's an error in your `for` loop or elsewhere in your document. Posting a fiddle with more of your javascript will definitely help troubleshoot it.

Comment: I can't see any for loop.

Comment: "also I am in the for loop but it is only giving for first values" Are you using a FOR loop? If yes, post relevant code of what you are talking about. You need to use a closure... BTW, IDs must be unique on context page

Answer (score 1):

> I am in the for loop

**i think by for loop you meant while generating your HTML** ...and if yes , that means you have same ids for multiple element (which is the reason , your are getting the first value always in alert). since you are using click event .. use `this` reference to get your attr..

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#rid").on('click', function (e) {
    var v = $(this).attr('reel');
    alert("hello");
});
});
```

i recommened you to look at [HTML5 data](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) attribute to store custom data.. and use [`jquery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to get/set.

**example**

```
<a href="#" id="rid" data-reel="4">Click me</a>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#rid").on('click', function (e) {
    var v = $(this).data('reel');
    alert(v);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

HTML

```
 <a href="#" id="rid" data-reel="4">Click me</a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#rid").on('click', function (e) {
        var v = $("#rid").data('reel');
        alert(v);
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PF2Vg/)

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#rid").on('click', function (e) {
        var v = $(this).attr('reel');
        alert("hello");
    });
});
```

Comment: A downvote for this is a bit harsh, and not explaining why is totally douchey.  Man up and explain yourself, if you can.